# Can't find numeric value index

Tags: r, vector, indexing, numeric

I have the following `a`:

```
> a
 [1] 0.32142857 0.21428571 0.10714286 0.46428571 0.42857143 0.57142857 0.35714286 0.50000000 0.67857143 0.07142857 0.92857143 0.60714286
[13] 0.17857143 0.25000000 1.00000000 0.71428571 0.64285714 0.78571429 0.57142857 0.28571429 0.57142857 0.39285714 0.96428571 0.85714286
[25] 0.75000000 0.53571429 0.82142857 0.14285714 0.39285714 0.21428571 0.03571429 0.89285714
> str (a)
 num [1:32] 0.321 0.214 0.107 0.464 0.429 ...
> class (a)
[1] "numeric"
```

I would like to find the index value for specific element.
When I use it for integer it works, but not for the others:

```
> which (a==1)
[1] 15
> which (a==0.10714286)
integer(0)
> match (0.10714286,a)
[1] NA
```

How can I get the index value `3` for `0.10714286`?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to search for the nearest value instead:

```
val <- 0.10714286
idx <- which.min(abs(a - val))
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what is a-val?

Comment: a (your vector) minus the value that you want to search for

Comment: Typically you'd do `which(abs(a - val) < tol)`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the vector to store the data. Kindly go through the following code:

```
> a=c(0.32142857,0.21428571,0.10714286,0.46428571,0.42857143)
  > str(a)
  num [1:5] 0.321 0.214 0.107 0.464 0.429
  > a[1]
  [1] 0.3214286
  > a[2]
  [1] 0.2142857
  > a[3]
  [1] 0.1071429
  > a[4]
  [1] 0.4642857
  > which(a==0.10714286)
  [1] 3
  > class(a)
  [1] "numeric"
  > match(0.10714286,a)
  [1] 3
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Hope this solution looks simple and easy for understanding.